# OpenLayers.Map change position of Attribution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have included an OpenLayers.Map in my site per JavaScript:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map();
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);
```

All works fine. Expect the position of the attribution (OpenStreetMap contributors). Are there any option move the attribution in the lower right corner?

Here is what i got currently:
[image: OpenStreetMap example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the default OL style for this component:

```
.olControlAttribution {
  left: 5px;
}
```

You can try this out by going to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/attributions.html and executing the following JS code in your browser's console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('olControlAttribution')[0].style.left='5px'
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what version is being used in this question but I was using V3 and had to use the following class to change the attribution instead:

```
.ol-attribution
```